# NSRunLoop is calling my selector after long Delay

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, macos, nsrunloop

Problem statement : we have one secondary thread in which we are doing all backend processing.In this secondary thread we have created a separate NSRunLoop to run. we create and use timer in this runloop

```
    NSAutoreleasePool *myPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSRunLoop * threadRL = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[threadRL addPort:[NSMachPort port] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[threadRL run];
[myPool release];
```

Every thing is run fine except one of the call to a selector is taking almost 10 second to execute and this happens randomly not every time.

```
[myclass performSelector:@selector(func) onThread:myThread withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

I tried this also with no difference.

```
[myclass performSelector:@selector(func) onThread:myThread withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO modes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: NSDefaultRunLoopMode, NSRunLoopCommonModes,nil]];
```

I am not doing any task in func which could possibly take this much time,

What I am thinking is that it might be possible that runloop is in different mode.

Is there a way to make fund be executed in highest priority i.e what ever is being executed in runloop be interrupted or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a NSTimer and set the firedate to now. Please see the sample  code below.

```
  NSTimer *timer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:now
                                                  interval:.01
                                                    target:myClass
                                                  selector:@selector(funct)
                                                  userInfo:nil
                                                   repeats:NO];

   NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
        [runLoop addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [runLoop run];
```

Comment: There are timer attached to this runloop. And many other performselector on the thread are working, but this func does not gets call for a long delay. The reason could be that run loop is processing something, But my requirement is to process func ASAP at the very high priority.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question. My runloop was waiting on NSInputStream:read when there was no byte to read. So the func was being queued on in runloop source but as the thread is waiting in on socket read nothing was getting executed.

I got to know this when I hooked the runloop and saw it is getting stuck there.